# When to use blocks

Tags: ruby

**I love Ruby blocks!** The idea behind them is just very very neat and convenient.

I have just looked back over my code from the past week or so, which is basically *every single ruby function I ever have written*, and I have noticed that not a single one of them returns a value! Instead of returning values, I always use a block to pass the data back!

I have even caught myself contemplating writing a little status class which would allow me to write code like :

```
something.do_stuff do |status|
  status.success do 
    # successful code
  end

  status.fail do
    # fail code
    puts status.error_message
  end
end
```

Am I using blocks too much? Is there a time to use blocks and a time to use return values?

Are there any gotchas to be aware of? Will my huge use of blocks come and bite me sometime?

Comment: Who says you can't use a block *and* return a value (when it's sensible)?

Comment: agreed - like IO::open - closes the file if you pass a block, returns the filehandle if not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The whole thing would be more readable as:

```
if something.do_stuff
  #successful code
else
  #unsuccessful code
end
```

or to use a common rails idiom:

```
if @user.save
  render :action=>:show
else
   @user.errors.each{|attr,msg| logger.info "#{attr} - #{msg}" }
   render :action=>:edit
end
```

IMHO, avoiding the return of a boolean value is overuse of code blocks.

A block makes sense if . . .

#### It allows code to use a resource without having to close that resource

```
 open("fname") do |f|
  # do stuff with the file
 end #don't have to worry about closing the file
```

#### The calling code would have to do non-trivial computation with the result

In this case, you avoid adding the return value to calling scope.  This also often makes sense with multiple return values.

```
something.do_stuff do |res1, res2|
   if res1.foo? and res2.bar?
      foo(res1)
   elsif res2.bar?
      bar(res2)
   end
 end #didn't add res1/res2 to the calling scope
```

#### Code must be called both before and after the yield

You see this in some of the rails helpers:

```
 <% content_tag :div do  %>
     <%= content_tag :span "span content" %>
  <% end -%>
```

And of course **iterators** are a great use case, as they're (considered by ruby-ists to be) prettier than `for` loops or [list comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension).

Certainly not an exhaustive list, but I recommend that you don't just use blocks because you can.

Comment: +1. I agree. I think blocks in the OP's example is not 'good ruby style' but blocks gone mad...

Comment: Blocks also appear frequently in DSL's, where they are used to encapsulate a scope (rake) or to make the code read more like a natural language (rspec).

Comment: I don't like the `if do_something_with_side_effects_and_possibly_long_delays` idiom. The block-based callback is nice because it separates methods based around side effects from methods based around computations, for one. It will also become more useful as parallelism becomes a bigger deal — the CPS version allows `do_stuff` to execute asynchronously and still have the succeed-fail logic called after it knows whether it's succeeded.

Comment: valid point, but certainly you don't agree with status.success { some_fn() }

Comment: As a general rule, no, that's not very idiomatic in Ruby.

Comment: @klochner, yup some excellent points there! I think you may have missed that the status object in the block contains more than just success and failure - it also contains an error message. So returning a simple boolean would cut out some of the possible functionality.

Comment: @Peter, why is it blocks gone mad? Is it just readability or is there something else?

Comment: @Pongus: it's blocks for the sake of blocks, rather than blocks for the good reasons above. There's nothing wrong with blocks when they're useful, but as @klochner said, don't use blocks just because you can.

Comment: @klochner, Excellent! That sums it all up nicely and makes a lot of sense. Thanks! :)

Comment: Essentially, use blocks where you use closures. Maybe a rule of thumb could be - when you see yourself passing a lot of arguments to methods?

Answer (score 13):

This is what functional programming people call ["continuation-passing style"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). It's a valid technique, though there are cases where it will tend to complicate things more than it's worth. It might be worth to relook some of the places where you're using it and see if that's the case in your code. But there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: Who downvoted this without comment? This *is* continuation-passing style, and it *is* an accepted way of structuring code in the right circumstances. I don't mean "accepted by me" — I mean, like, "this is a technique that has been used by well-respected computer scientists since before many people on this site were born."

Comment: I just really want to know what the objection is. As far as I know, my answer is as close to fact (rather than opinion) as it could possibly be.

Comment: I see no reason for a downvote here! You taught me something. Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I like this style. It's actually very Ruby-like, and often you'll see projects restructure their code to use this format instead of something less readable.

Returning values makes sense where returning values makes sense. If you have an `Article` object, you want `article.title` to return the title. But for this particular example of callbacks, it's stellar style, and it's good that you know how to use them. I suspect that many new to Ruby will never figure out how to do it well.

Comment: Yup, a good example where returning a value is obviously better than blocks!