# Ruby: when to use code blocks and how to know if should pass one to a method?

Tags: ruby, block

I'm starting to learn Ruby and trying to understand code blocks, as I'm a programmer with C# and Java background.
I think I understand the concept on passing a block and using yield. However, based on my background, in what situations are blocks useful (I never used code blocks/clojures before, so I don't understand why they are so useful)?
Other thing is I would like to know is: if I start working on an existing project, with some APIs already developed etc, how will I know if I should pass a block to a certain API method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180903/when-to-use-blocks

Answer (score 2):

If you used lambdas much in C#, blocks might be familiar in the sense that they're both chunks of anonymous code that get passed around.

Blocks are used all the time in idiomatic Ruby.  They're used in place of 'for' loops,

```
1.upto(10) do |i|
    puts i
end
```

or to iterate through collections,

```
["New York", "Chicago", "Los Angeles"].each do |city|
    puts "I wish I wasn't in #{city}!"
end
```

or in a similar way to a C# 'using' statement to work with files.

```
File.open("test-file", "w") do |f|
    f.puts "Hello, world!"
end
```

Usually API documentation will explicitly state when a block is expected and provide an example.  I don't think it's much worry about.